# REST API EXPRESS JS: Can not download file in Reactjs, which is send by back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, api, express

I created REST API using Express JS to send Excel file:

```
app.get('/download/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
       await res.download('./ExcelCopy.xlsx');
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});
```

But in Reactjs when I connect to API nothing happens, but redux tells everything went well:

```
export const getExcel = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await dispatch(getExcelRequest());
  try {
    await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/download/');
    dispatch(getExcelSuccess());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    dispatch(getExcelFailed());
  }
};
```

*What should I do in order to download a file from back-end using react js*

Comment: Are you getting any error in the browser console?

Comment: no, Im getting nothing. If I in browser type local **http://127.0.0.1:8888/download/** it downloads Excel file as expected

Comment: You can use filesaver npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Comment: A similar kind of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460162/react-excel-file-download-corrupt/46331201

Comment: broo, thank you, that's a answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React excel file download corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43460162/react-excel-file-download-corrupt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `response type` and use npm package [**file-saver**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) to download the file.

> Modified Code:

```
export const getExcel = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await dispatch(getExcelRequest());
  try {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/download/', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
      .then((response) => {
         var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
              fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'data.xlsx');
              dispatch(getExcelSuccess());

       });        
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(getExcelFailed());
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not just send a get request to download the file. Instead I would suggest you to use this module named [js-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download).

Example usage:

```
const FileDownload = require('js-file-download');

const response = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8888/download/')
FileDownload(response.data, 'ExcelCopy.xlsx');
```

Hope it helps.